# is there any way compute image client size before loading( with js)?

Tags: javascript, google-image-search

how google image create a background that size is same with  image that is not loaded ?

is there any way compute image client size before loading with js?

I want to creat something like google image but dont know how compute that background size before loading image .

I found out  image must be loaded for getting client size but is other way for get or compute it?

Comment: Maybe [background-attachment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) ...? No need to know the size of the image.

Comment: In JS you can detect image size on load:

(in Head section)...

- Create global variables: var pic=new Image(), picW=-1, picH=-1
- Set pic.onload function: pic.onload=function() {picW=pic.width; picH=pic.height;}

pic.onload gets called whenever you set pic.src